# Quartz in Spring, like that scheduler in Android?

Tags: android, scheduling

I searched a lot. But i can't get the solution for it. In Spring, `Quartz` is used as a scheduler to repeat the particular task. Likewise in android, what is the scheduler is available to do the task repeatedly at the particular time intervals. I need a scheduler for Android and also i want to avoid memory leakage. I am having 5 different types of settings. All having the update interval time option. So i want to get the information from server based on the interval time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If running within your Activity or service, use [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Further, there is [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for extended schedules, and Commonware's excellent extension of a [`WakefulIntent`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Comment: Timer seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: You use TimerTask with Timer. You'd use AlarmManager with an IntentService.

Comment: So, this will assure no memory leakage?

Comment: This isn't iOS, memory leakage is not a major concern. Timer/TimerTask won't cause memory leaks, unless you leak UI elements in your TimerTask itself.