# Executors.newScheduledThreadPool gaps in execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a requirement where I need to run a task every 15 seconds.

I have seen several articles suggesting to use `ScheduledExecutorService` rather than `TimerTask` which I'm doing.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Some task
        }
};
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
            .newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    scheduler
            .scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Th problem is that the **runnable does not execute** in between randomly, maybe for 1...2..5 minutes sometimes.

I have my try catch in place and there is no exception or error.

I added a date-time log

> time2 : 2015-12-10T11:28:00.000+04:00
>
> time2 : 2015-12-10T11:28:00.000+04:00
>
> time2 : 2015-12-10T11:29:00.000+04:00
>
> time2 : 2015-12-10T11:31:00.000+04:00
>
> time2 : 2015-12-10T11:31:00.000+04:00

As you can see the runnable was not executed for 11:30

Why is this skip? The timer is doing the same task every time & I think it's unlikely that delay in the previous task causes this delay.

I tried increasing the pool-size from 1 to 5, but still the same result.

If this is a thread issue...Than I know I have certain options which I can use instead of `newScheduledThreadPool`. Like `newCachedThreadPool` ,`newFixedThreadPool` ,`newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` .

All I want to do is execute a certain task every 15 seconds & execute it every time even if the previous task took long to complete or had any exception.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you considered this: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Hey..Is it reliable? What will be the down side of using alarms?

Comment: Pretty reliable. Especially if it shall run beyond the runtime of your activity. If it shall only be active during runtime of your app, you could go for Handler/Thread/Timer - combination as suggested in that article.

Comment: thanks..i will give it a try and see..The task is running in a background service.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't give you real-time guarantees on time. I'd advise you to log both starting and ending time of your job. There is statement for scheduleAtFixedRate apidoc

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

check that it is not your case.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: hey...I logged the the start time and end time and difference between that is of milliseconds. The problem is not in the task i'm doing. Anyways, Is there anyway I can concurrently execute my task even though previous task is longer then my delay?

Comment: you can launch new thread inside your scheduled task. In that case your scheduled task should finish fast.

Comment: This is my first android app & i'm not that well versed with threads. I would like to avoid creating it myself unless I know I'm managing it properly. How about newCachedThreadPool option? Doc says that it reuses old threads if available & create if there are none.

Comment: I think it is safe choice. But bear in mind that if your jobs will be slow, they will fill all pool and no new jobs will be launched. By the way if any of your tasks (not wrapped in  thread) will cause an exception, scheduling will be cancelled, so be careful in exception handling inside scheduled job.

Comment: CachedThreadPool does not fullfill your criteria for executing the task every 15 seconds. You need to use either Timer or TimerTask for your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823717/quartz-in-spring-like-that-scheduler-in-android